# URL.action goes to server , but not the root URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

Newbie to MVC, please excuse me if my question is not clear.

My view - https://abc.somecompany.org/ has the URL (being generated in a home controller )

```
@Url.Action("Index", "ContName" ,
                new { id = viewModel.Id }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

When I deploy it to the dev server, instead of showing the URL as

```
https://abc.somecompany.org/ContName/
```

or

```
https://abc.somecompany.org/ContName/Index
```

It is being changed to `https://abc-server-8088/ContName`, which obviously does not work outside the organization .

Why is the root URL being changed from `abc.somecompany.org/` to `abc-server-8088`? Similar issue in both dev and test. This is being changed to something else

Do not want to change it to URL Content , because i have action and controller

```
viewModel.URLLINK = Url.Action(Etion.Index, Entroller.ContName,
                new { id = viewModel.Id }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Want the same root URL (~) to show up in the emails

Comment: What happens when you call this line `@Url.Action("Index", "ContName",new { id = viewModel.Id }, Request.Url.Scheme);` without the `Request.Url.Scheme`.  Simply use `@Url.Action("Index", "ContName", new { id = viewModel.Id });`. I've never seen `Request.Url.Scheme` passed in most examples of `Url.Action()` and is a likely candidate for the cause of your issue.

Comment: Can you show your route.config contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution:

```
@{
    var myLink = $"{Request.Url.Scheme}://{Request.Url.Host}{@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = @Model.id })}";
    <a href="@myLink">Link</a>
}
```

---

**A short Review:**

1. **Html.ActionLink** generates an `<a href=".."></a>` tag. Forexample:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123", foo=5 },  new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

generates:

```
    <a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123?foo=5">link text</a>
```

2. **Url.Action** returns only a url. Forexmple, `Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })` generates:

```
     /somecontroller/someaction/123
```

But, the nice point about `Url.action` is that you can combine it with anchor tag to create the link content on the fly. For instance:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = @Model.id })">
    <img src="@Model.src" />
</a>
```